# Show queries spilling to disk in real time

Tags: postgresql, performance, monitoring

I have been asked to write a query to show queries that are currently spilling to disk (i.e. creating temp files because they have run out of work_mem) so that the queries can be killed.

I cannot see a way to monitor this in real time. We have `pg_stat_statements` enabled, I have queried `pg_stat_database`, and I'm aware that this can be logged in the postgres logs by using the `log_temp_files` setting. However none of these appear to fulfil this requirement because they are all showing either cumulative stats or the logs only write the log entry when the query has completed.

Is it possible to display a list of queries that are currently running and writing to temp files?

(I'm aware that the best way to deal with this long-term is to optimise the queries, adjust the work_mem overall, adjust the work_mem only for the offending queries etc. However my boss wants a faster stop-gap measure of this monitoring & query killing approach before getting to the next step of reducing the number of queries writing temp files).

Comment: Have you tried [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)? E.g `select * from pg_stat_activity where wait_type_event='IO' and wait_event='BufFileWrite';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly kill such statements. Simply set `temp_file_limit = 0` in the PostgreSQL configuration, and PostgreSQL will automatically cancel queries that use temporary files.

If you don't want to forbid the creation of temporary files, but you want to cancel all statements that use temporary files if a certain limit is exceeded, you could use a statement like this:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   temp_limit CONSTANT bigint := 1073741824;
   temp bigint;
   pid integer;
BEGIN
   FOR pid, temp IN
      SELECT regexp_replace(
                name,
                '^pgsql_tmp([0-9]*).[0-9]*$',
                '\1'
             )::integer AS pid,
             coalesce(sum(size), 0)
      FROM pg_ls_tmpdir()
      GROUP BY ROLLUP (pid)
      ORDER BY pid NULLS FIRST
   LOOP
      /* this is always the first result row */
      EXIT WHEN pid IS NULL AND temp <= temp_limit;

      /* cancel a query that uses temp files */
      PERFORM pg_cancel_backend(pid);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Running that statement is cheap, but not free. I think that setting `temp_file_limit` is the better approach. Yes, that only limits temp usage by a single backend, but if you set it to a tenth of the free disk space or so, you are practically safe from your disk being filled up with temporary files.

Comment: The issue is that temp files are occasionally filling up the disk when there are lots of them at once. But looking at this it seems that it is a limit per transaction rather than for the whole DB. I don't think that will work for us because we only want to use block these when the total temp storage is over a certain threshold.

Comment: You didn't say so in your question.